# How to center and scale a tikz picture at the same time for beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, adjustbox, tikzscale, rmarkdown

I need to scale donw a Tikz picture and center it on my frame (I am using Rmarkdown).
I have tried several options: `scalebox`, `transform canvas`, `adjustbox`, `scale`, `begin{center}`, `centering`, etc...

But when I scale down the figure, it does not center, and vice versa. Here is my code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Guilherme"
date: "3/17/2021"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: /home/guilherme/GoogleDrive/Analises/Modelo/extra_settings2.tex
---

## Frame
\scalebox{.6}{
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, fill=blue!15, 
        text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, fill=blue!15, 
        text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
        minimum height=2em]
    \node [block] (mcglm) {MCGLM};
    \node [block, right of=mcglm] (poissons) {Poisson sample};
    \node [block, right of=poissons] (poissonf) {Poisson full data};
    \node [block, right of=poissonf] (negbins) {NB sample};
    \node [decision, above of=poissonf] (est1) {1ºPORT 2ºBFGS 3ºPORT};
    \node [block, below of=mcglm] (negbinf) {NB full data};
    \node [block, right of=negbinf] (cmps) {COM-Poisson sample};
    \node [decision, below of=negbinf] (est2) {1ºPORT 2ºBFGS 3ºPORT};
    \node [block, right of=cmps] (cmpf) {COM-Poisson full data};
    \node [decision, below of=cmpf] (est3) {1ºPORT 2ºBFGS 3ºPORT};
    \path [line] (mcglm) -- (poissons);
    \path [line] (poissons) -- (poissonf);
    \path [line] (poissonf) -- (negbins);
    \path [line] (negbins) -- node {} +(2,0) |- node {} (0,-1.5) -| node {} (0,-2.1);
    \path [line] (negbinf) -- (cmps);
    \path [line] (cmps) -- (cmpf);
    \path [line] (poissonf) edge[bend left] node [below left] {} (est1);
    \path [line] (est1) edge[bend left] node [below left] {} (poissonf);
    \path [line] (negbinf) edge[bend right] node [below left] {} (est2);
    \path [line] (est2) edge[bend right] node [below left] {} (negbinf);
    \path [line] (cmpf) edge[bend right] node [below left] {} (est3);
    \path [line] (est3) edge[bend right] node [below left] {} (cmpf);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

`extra_settings2.tex` file:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}% Package for below command
\tikzstyle{square}=[draw]        % It defines square for graph
\usepackage{adjustbox}           % It resizes tikz pictures
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? You can also replace the `\hspace*{\fill}` with the commented out `center` environment, but I like how this matches the `\vspace*{\fill}`

[image: beamer]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}% Package for below command
\tikzstyle{square}=[draw]        % It defines square for graph
\usepackage{adjustbox}           % It resizes tikz pictures
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,calc,backgrounds}


\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}

% \begin{center}
\hspace*{\fill} \scalebox{0.5}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, fill=blue!15, 
        text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, fill=blue!15, 
        text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
        minimum height=2em]
    \node [block] (mcglm) {MCGLM};
    \node [block, right of=mcglm] (poissons) {Poisson sample};
    \node [block, right of=poissons] (poissonf) {Poisson full data};
    \node [block, right of=poissonf] (negbins) {NB sample};
    \node [decision, above of=poissonf] (est1) {1ºPORT 2ºBFGS 3ºPORT};
    \node [block, below of=mcglm] (negbinf) {NB full data};
    \node [block, right of=negbinf] (cmps) {COM-Poisson sample};
    \node [decision, below of=negbinf] (est2) {1ºPORT 2ºBFGS 3ºPORT};
    \node [block, right of=cmps] (cmpf) {COM-Poisson full data};
    \node [decision, below of=cmpf] (est3) {1ºPORT 2ºBFGS 3ºPORT};
    \path [line] (mcglm) -- (poissons);
    \path [line] (poissons) -- (poissonf);
    \path [line] (poissonf) -- (negbins);
    \path [line] (negbins) -- node {} +(2,0) |- node {} (0,-1.5) -| node {} (0,-2.1);
    \path [line] (negbinf) -- (cmps);
    \path [line] (cmps) -- (cmpf);
    \path [line] (poissonf) edge[bend left] node [below left] {} (est1);
    \path [line] (est1) edge[bend left] node [below left] {} (poissonf);
    \path [line] (negbinf) edge[bend right] node [below left] {} (est2);
    \path [line] (est2) edge[bend right] node [below left] {} (negbinf);
    \path [line] (cmpf) edge[bend right] node [below left] {} (est3);
    \path [line] (est3) edge[bend right] node [below left] {} (cmpf);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\hspace*{\fill}
% \end{center}

\vspace*{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be successful using `resizebox`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
    \resizebox{.8\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```